# What should the brake force in this problem be?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, vectors

Alright so I think I know how to do this but I require help in calculating what acceleration would be in terms of some sort of friction coefficient.

So model a particle going down a hill. The slope is 25 degrees. The mass of the particle is 50kg and the coefficient of sliding friction between the particle and slope is 0.05. When the brake is applied, 260N acts in the opposite direction to the motion of the particle. g = 9.8ms^-2

I won't write out my entire workings are they're lengthy, but I'll give the line I am up to which is:

let $\mu$ = the coefficient of sliding friction

let $b$ = the braking force

$ma_i = (mg \cos{65}-\mu bN)\hat{\mathbf{i}} + (N-mg \sin{65})\hat{\mathbf{j}}$

So I should imagine that b is going to slow down the acceleration, so perhaps it's as simple as 0.05 x 240?

I'm not sure if it would be 240 or 2.4 though, for example - any elucidation on this?

Comment: You should really use LaTeX to format your mathematical expressions.  If you aren't going to do that then you should very carefully use parentheses, indicate subscripts using the underscore, etc.  Otherwise people will find it very hard to follow what you have written.  I'm going to edit your post to use LaTeX.  You should then edit my edited version, just so you see how I did it.

Comment: Frankly, once you have it clear enough in non-LaTeX notation, you can pretty much throw some dollar signs around the whole thing and it'll turn out looking decent. There's really no excuse not to do LaTeX.

Comment: Yes I didn't think it would be that simple. I have since learned my lesson, thanks gleedadswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the angle of the slope be $\theta$, $m$ the mass,  $a$ the acceleration, $\mu$ the friction coefficient and $g=9.8 ms^{-2}$.

On the mass acts a vertical gravitational force $mg$. Decompose this into a component along the line of the hill, so that is $mg\sin\theta$, and one perpendicular to that, so $mg\cos\theta$.

The latter provides a friction force $\mu mg\cos\theta$.

The balance of forces acting on the particle along the hill’s surface is thus:

$ma= mg\sin\theta - \mu mg\cos \theta$.

Using the OP’s numbers: $ma=185N$.

Applying a braking force of $260 N$ would result in a decelerating force of $185N-260N=-75N$.

Deceleration would be $a=-\frac{75N}{50kg}=-1.5ms^{-2}$.

Comment: Hi Gert. Thanks for your answer. I tried to compute my numbers with your equation. I got $ma=(50*9.8*sin{65}) - (0.05*50*cos{65}) = 237N$. I assume I missed something?

Comment: If the angle $\theta$ is the angle between the hill's downward slope and the horizon, then why use $\theta=65$ degrees? That angle is **$25$ degrees**, as you stated. 65 is seriously steep, you know?

Comment: An e.g. in the textbook, one of the questions says the angle to the horizontal is 30 and then uses 60. Here it says 25, so I used 65. For example: "A skier slides under gravity alone down a straight, smooth ski slope, which is inclined at an angle of 30◦ to the horizontal." Which in the calculations they later give as: "The forces acting are the weight W of the skier and the normal
reaction N of the slope on the skier. A force diagram is shown below. The acute angle between W and the i-direction is
180◦− 90◦− 30◦= 60◦."

Comment: You are 'overthinking' this. Your original statement "The slope is 25 degree" would mean to most people familiar with this kind of simple problem the following. Assuming the surface on which the particle travels is straight and smooth, then the angle between that surface and the horizontal is 25 degrees. It's possible that the problem was stated as 25 degrees between the surface and the **vertical**, in which case $\theta = 90-25=65$ degrees. It's your responsibility to define the problem unambiguously, we're not mind-readers!

Comment: It's one of the reasons why including a **diagram of the geometry** in your question **would have been really useful**. In the absence of that we have to interpret your written statement.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark up the answer(s) that you like. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The retarding force from friction is $50g \cdot 0.05$ Newtons, acting up the hill.  If the particle is sliding, most brakes will not be effective as you have already accounted for the sliding friction.  If the brake is effective, it will add a force of $260$ Newtons up the hill, as you are given the force.  You can then resolve these into vertical and horizontal if you want, but I would just treat it as a one dimensional problem with the axis along the slope.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ross. $μbN$ is basically what I took to be the retarding force up the hill. with the $b$ being the braking force. Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: If you are using $\mu$ for the coefficient of friction, as I read the problem it should not apply to the braking force.  You say the brake exerts $260$N, so that is the force.  It doesn't say how it is applied, nor does it matter.

Comment: May I know why? Apologies for not understanding. I would have thought that the CoE x braking force x N would give me the forces acting up because the braking force would have an efficiency given by the CoE?

Comment: The braking force is applied to the particle.  There is no coefficient to apply.  (What is CoE?)  The friction coefficient is used to convert the downward force due to gravity to lateral friction force, but if the brake apply 260N to the particle that is the force.

Comment: Hah sorry I meant CoF. So my approach was R, the resultant force being given by $R=N+F+W$ where $N$ is the normal reaction, $F$ is the lateral friction force and $W$ is the weight. Originally I had $F=-μbN$ but interpret your "but if the brake apply 260N to the particle that is the force" as meaning I have gotten it wrong? Edit: Unless you're saying that 260N IS F, and thus $260N=-μN$

Comment: No, I was saying there is another term, the braking force.  Just add it in.  Imagine you hook a spring to the particle and pull it enough that the spring applies 260N.  That is the brake.  I would just project on the hill, so gravity supplies $+50 g \sin 25^\circ$.  Friction supplies $-50 g 0.05 \cos 25^\circ \sin 25^\circ$.  The brake supplies $-260$.  Add them up and you have the resultant.